# what is the gradient of an implicit function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Assume $u:\mathbb{R^{3}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$ is smooth for $x \in \mathbb{R^{3}}$. Let $$f(x)=u(x,t-|x|)$$ what is the gradient of $f$? Is the components partial derivatives of $f$, i.e. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{3}}$$ Or also a $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}$? I'm a little confused since this function $u$ maps from a product space to real line. By the way, this is from a wave equation problem, and $t$ denotes the time.

Any idea?

Comment: As you wrote it, $t$ must be considered a fixed number. Hence the gradient of $f$ at any point is a vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose components are the partial derivatives with respect to $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

Comment: It depends on the context. It is most likely just the derivative w.r.t. the spatial coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote for clarity the first argument of $u$ by $y$ and the second one by $s$.

This will alow you to write

$$\partial_{x_1} f(x) = \partial_{y_1}u (x,t-|x|)\cdot \partial_{x_1} x_1
+\partial_{y_2}u (x,t-|x|)\cdot \partial_{x_1} x_2+\partial_{y_3}u (x,t-|x|)\cdot \partial_{x_1} x_3+\partial_{s}u (x,t-|x|)\cdot \partial_{x_1} (t-|x|) $$

$$ = \partial_{y_1}u (x,t-|x|) 
-\partial_{s}u (x,t-|x|)\cdot \frac{x_1}{|x|}.  $$

With that you have
$$\nabla_x f(x) = \nabla_y u(x,t-|x|) - \frac{x}{|x|}\partial_s u(x,t-|x|)  $$

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder if you could help on another question I asked before which is about computing the divergence:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038262/compute-the-divergence        The setting is the same